# fruitless type test: a value of type Option[akka.actor.ActorSystem] cannot also be a akka.actor.ActorSystem

Tags: scala, warnings, static-analysis

I am using scapegoat for static code analysis i am getting a warning message

```
fruitless type test: a value of type Option[akka.actor.ActorSystem] cannot also be a akka.actor.ActorSystem
```

here is my code

```
object ActorSystemSetting extends ActorSystemSettingTrait{
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

  var actorSystem  :  Option[ActorSystem] = None
   def createActorSystem: Option[ActorSystem] = {
      actorSystem = Option(ActorSystem("ArteciateActorSystem", config))
      actorSystem
    }

  def getActorSystem  :  Option[ActorSystem] ={
    if (actorSystem == None){
      createActorSystem
    }
    else{
     log.debug("ActorSystem is not null")
    }
    actorSystem
  } 
}
```

In this section i am getting warning message 
on the line

```
case Some(system: ActorSystem) =>




   Option(ActorSystemSetting.getActorSystem) match {
          case Some(system: ActorSystem) =>
            system.actorOf(Props[PaymentViaCreditDeletionActor]
              , name = "PaymentViaCreditDeletionActor")
          case None => log.debug("ActorSystem is null")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change this

```
Option(ActorSystemSetting.getActorSystem) match {
```

to just this:

```
ActorSystemSetting.getActorSystem match {
```

`ActorSystemSetting.getActorSystem` already returns `Option(ActorSystem)` so you don't need to wrap it in another `Option`.

It is not working because you are trying to match a value of type `Option[Option[ActorSystem]]` with `Some(system: ActorSystem)`, which is of type `Option[ActorSystem]` so it can never match.